# Переклад прислів'я з російської мови

Tags: росіянізм

Цікавить переклад прислів'я *"Что написано пером, того не вырубишь топором".*

[Google перекладач](https://translate.google.com/?hl=uk#view=home&op=translate&sl=ru&tl=uk&text=%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC%2C%20%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%88%D1%8C%20%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC) подає, як

> Що написано пером, того не вирубати сокирою

На мою думку це не зовсім вдалий преклад. Можливо є кращий переклад? Або відповідник українською мовою в значені, що написано те не повернути.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В [Українсько-російскому і російсько-українському фразеологічному словнику (Олейник І. С., Сидоренко М. М.)](http://lang.slovopedia.org.ua/7/53415/102535.html) знаходимо:

> **ЧТО НАПИСАНО ПЕРОМ, ТОГО НЕ ВЫРУБИШЬ ТОПОРОМ**
>   що написано пером, того не витягнеш (не виволочеш) волом; написаного пером не витягнеш і волом; написаного сокирою не вирубаєш; скажеш - не вернеш, напишеш - не зітреш, відрубаєш - не приточиш